# RegExp, Regex только для Иврита (Hebrew) + возможность добавления новой строки

Tags: javascript, reactjs, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

```
const onlyHebrewPattern = new RegExp(/^[\u0590-\u05FF ,.'^-]+$/i);
```

Есть вот такой вот **RegExp**, не получается сделать новую строку по нажатию enter.

В обработчике событий в `textarea` добавил

```
onKeyPress={event => {
    if (!onlyHebrewPattern.test(event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

  }
```

Comment: Может, `const onlyHebrewPattern = new RegExp(/^[\u0590-\u05FF ,.'^\r\n-]+$/);`?

Answer (score 0):

Для мультистрочной обработки текста необходимо добавить `m` флаг:

```
const onlyHebrewPattern = new RegExp(/^[\u0590-\u05FF ,.'^-]+$/im);
```

Comment: Также не работает :(

Comment: странно, я тестил с англ. языком работает

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в регулярное выражение `\r` и `\n`:

```js
const onlyHebrewPattern = new RegExp(/^[\u0590-\u05FF ,.'^\r\n-]+$/);
```

Выражение `^[\u0590-\u05FF ,.'^\r\n-]+$` найдет любую строку, состоящую из ивритских символов, пробелов, запятых, точек, одиночных кавычек, знака `^`, `-` и символов перехода на новую строку.

Comment: Не работает почему-то, может неправильно делаю проверку?
if (!onlyHebrewPattern.test(event.key)) { event.preventDefault() }

Comment: @hitFM Нужно проверять целый текст.

Answer (score 0):

```
onKeyPress={event => {
    if (!onlyHebrewPattern.test(event.key)) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            console.info('good');
        } else {
            console.info('not good');
            event.preventDefault();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Enter почему-то не попадал под выражение.

Решил вопрос следующим образом.